# Search with MongoDB in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

It will search on writing complete word as it is only and I want to show the results of all those words which are starting from it. Like after typing pro it should display all the words starting with pro like product1, product2 , etc.

Here is my products controller's index action
      def index

```
if params[:search]
    @products = Product.search(params[:search]).order("created_at ASC")
  else
    flash[:alert]= "No matches Found."
    @products = Product.all
  end
```

end

Model

```
 class Product
 include Mongoid::Document

 embeds_many :brands
 field :name, type: String
 field :description, type: String
 field :price, type: Float


def self.search(query)
  any_of({name: query})
end
end
```

Please help me to define a proper search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **RegEx** search for this. As,

```
Product.any_of(name: /^pro/) #all products starting with "pro"
Product.any_of(name: /pro$/) #all products ending with "pro"
Porduct.any_of(name: /pro/) #all products having "pro" anywhere in name
```

Comment: but when i write  any_of({name: /^query/}), it won't find any product

Comment: query in your case is nothing just an variable. so you need to query in such a way `Product.any_of(name: /^#{query}/)` to get the desired result.

Comment: that worked... thanks... but when I search a word which is not there then it shows flash msg "No matches found" but it won't show all products. Why is that happening?

Comment: because you are asking in the query just to return products/documents which matches the query you enter. In case, if there is no match, you want to show all the results, then you have to do something like `products= Product.any_of(name: /^#{query}/); products = Product.all unless products.any?` But that doesn't seems to be a valid solution for anything.....may be your requirements are different. In case you have any doubt do let me know.